# Imposing boundary conditions AND self-similarity on a PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, dimensional-analysis

I have a PDE in the form
$$u_t=F(u,u_x)$$
where the unknown is $u(x,t)$ on say $\mathbb R\times[0,\infty)$. $F$ is very nonlinear so I was told to assume self-similarity in the form
$$u(x,t)=t\tilde u(x)$$
to reduce it to an ODE. I have convinced myself based on the dimensions of the variables involved that this is the appropriate scaling.

My confusion is how then to deal with the boundary conditions at $t=0$. I'm interested in having some particular Dirichlet conditions there, but the scaling assumption seems to force $u(x,0)=0$ for all $x$. I guess this would be because the equation is only approximately self-similar, and then it somehow ``forgets'' about the boundary condition over time? Is there any way around this?

Comment: I do not see how the PDE could have similarity solutions of the form that is indicated with F regular at (0,0). On the other hand, if F is not regular at (0,0), there may not be uniqueness of solutions. If the advisor who gave you this problem is a fields medalist as you indicated on another forum, he is probably not part of the cottage industry which endlessly looks for similarity solutions for their own sake. Is there a broader context which you did not indicate?

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I can give one (regular) example: $$ u_t = F(u,u_x) \equiv 1 $$ with initial condition $u \equiv 0$. But it is not terribly nonlinear. :-)

Comment: Joking aside, I largely agree with Michael. There are only two ways you can have a solution on $\mathbb{R}\times (0,\infty)$ of the given form $u(t,x) = t \tilde{u}(x)$. First is if $F(x,y)$ is scaling homogeneous (meaning $F(\lambda x,\lambda y) = F(x,y)$ for all $\lambda > 0$) restricted to the cone generated by $\{ (u(1,x), u_x(1,x))\}$. Then $F$ is either constant on that cone or irregular at the origin. Second is if $F(0,0) = 0$ and you have the solution $u\equiv 0$ which is in the form you wrote.